# Show data from two tables which have same column name

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two table in Access, Employee and Dept.

In Employee table there is empname column and deptcode column, while in Dept table there is deptcode column and deptname column.

I want to do a query which shows empname, deptcode and deptname in a new table. I have tried:

```
SELECT empname, deptcode, deptname
  FROM employee,dept
```

And it cannot work as the deptcode exist in both table and it creates error. Can anyone kindly tell me how to solve this error problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to alias your tables in the FROM clause and then use the table alias in the SELECT statement.

```
select e.empname,d.deptcode,d.deptname 
from employee e
inner join dept d
  on e.deptcode = d.deptcode;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your method is new for me and it works!

Answer (score 2):

You just need to associate the columns with the tables in the form of aliases or table name itself. Something like this should work.

```
select employee.empname,
dept.deptcode,
dept.deptname from employee,dept 
where employee.deptcode = dept.deptcode;
```

Note that I have added a condition to match the department code for the employees

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works and this answer also teaches me new method.